# JS: Concatenating $(this).val() to get an id name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to hover over an h1 and trigger a glowing effect on a span whose id is stored in the value of the h1. I have a working example set up of how the glowing will work with a sentence, but I can't get it to work with the h1. I want to be able to hover over one of the h1s and cause the square of the same colour to glow. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#verb").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".verb").addClass("hovered");
  });
  $("#verb").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".verb").removeClass("hovered");
  });

  $("#noun").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".noun").addClass("hovered");
  });
  $("#noun").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".noun").removeClass("hovered");
  });


  $("h1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#".concat($(this).val())).addClass("hovered");
  });


});
```

```css
._21 {
  color: red !important
}

._106 {
  color: orange !important
}


/*glowing effect*/

#verb {
  color: blue
}

#noun {
  color: blue
}

.hovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span id="verb">Verbs</span> &nbsp; - &nbsp; <span id="noun">Nouns</span>
</p>

I <span class="verb">like</span> 
to <span class="verb">ride</span> 
my <span class="noun">bicycle</span> 
every <span class="noun">day</span>
.
<br><br>

<h1 class="_21" value="red">
  Red
</h1>
<h1 class="_106" value="orange">
  Orange
</h1>

<p style="font-size: 28px">
  <span class="_21" id="red">■</span>
  <span class="_106" id="orange">■</span>
</p>
```

Comment: `.` is not a concantenater in javascript.  I think you mean `+`: `$('#' + concat($(this).val()).addClass(...)`

Comment: @cale_b they are using the [string method concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) directly off the string literal, so `".".concat()` is same as `a="."; a.concat()`

Comment: Although the solution below might work, there is no `value` attribute for `h1` tags. Use [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to add custom attributes e.g. `data-value`. In your JS, use `$(this).data('value')` or `this.dataset.value`.

Comment: StackOverflow has it's own run-able snippet engine. Please use that instead of JSFiddle in order to future proof the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's typical to use `+` to concatenate strings in JavaScript instead of the `.concat()` method, although `.concat()` will work too. `+` is a little simpler and will be more familiar to people who read your code. In fact I had totally forgotten that strings had a `.concat()` method when I first looked at your code!

As noted on [the MDN page for `.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat), `+` and `+=` also perform better, although that wouldn't matter in a simple case like this.

As Patrick and Mikey noted, `h1` elements don't have a `value`, but you can use `data-value` instead.

And for a simple task like toggling a class on or off, you can use the single-argument version of jQuery's `.hover()`, where you give one function that gets called both on `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Put those together and it might look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#verb").hover( function() {
    $(".verb").toggleClass("hovered");
  });

  $("#noun").hover( function() {
    $(".noun").toggleClass("hovered");
  });

  $("h1").hover( function() {
    $( "#" + $(this).data('value') ).toggleClass("hovered");
  });

});
```

```css
._21 {
  color: red !important
}

._106 {
  color: orange !important
}


/*glowing effect*/

#verb {
  color: blue
}

#noun {
  color: blue
}

.hovered {
  transition: text-shadow 0.1s linear;
  text-shadow: 0 0 3px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <span id="verb">Verbs</span> &nbsp; - &nbsp; <span id="noun">Nouns</span>
</p>

I <span class="verb">like</span> 
to <span class="verb">ride</span> 
my <span class="noun">bicycle</span> 
every <span class="noun">day</span>
.
<br><br>

<h1 class="_21" data-value="red">
  Red
</h1>
<h1 class="_106" data-value="orange">
  Orange
</h1>

<p style="font-size: 28px">
  <span class="_21" id="red">■</span>
  <span class="_106" id="orange">■</span>
</p>
```

Comment: OP is using the concat property off the string literal,ie using `.` as a property accessor and not a concatenation operator.

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me, I totally forgot about the `.concat()` method of strings. Updating now to make it less silly...

Comment: Also note that h1's do not have a value, they probably meant to use the innerText/textContext or as Mikey mentions in the comments using a data-* attribute instead

Comment: I got it working by using '+' to concatenate and accessing data-value by replacing '$(this).val()' with 'this.getAttribute('data-value')'

Comment: Thanks for helping me to cut down on unnecessary code with 'hover' instead of 'mouseenter' and 'mouseleave'.